# how to solve concurrency problem in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, concurrency

while two users are editing their data from different location, 
when both clicks submit button at the same time, one user information is inserted in other user information automatically..

i do not know why this happens..

Need help to solve this issue.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: can you post some code for the edit/insert methods?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. where is the information being stored.

Comment: Are they working on the same data? (isn't really clear from the question)

Comment: Smells like bad use of static members. You need to provide some code so anyone can actually tell what's wrong.

Comment: no they are editing their property listing information at same time. so when they click on update button at same time, some of their information is inserted in another user property

Comment: He want to say that, if two user open the same page and trying to update record and if they hit the update button at the same time in web environment, How can he be able to deal in such situation.

Comment: These responses are lending good credence to @rciq's comment.  But it's all just guessing until we see the code.

Comment: string strReturn = objDBMethods.ExecStoreProcedure("sp_update_property", objDBMethods.strParam, objDBMethods.strParamVal);

Comment: @bhargav: You'll definitely want to edit the question to include that code.  It's entirely unreadable as comments.

Comment: @bhargav: Also, we may need more than just the handful of lines for the data access.  If you can reproduce the problem from end-to-end with as little code as possible, that entire stack would be useful.

Comment: @David: okay so can i show you the source code of edit button? from where all editable data passed to database

Comment: @bhargav: We'll need to see any code relevant to the problem.  It's likely that this is more than just the database objects.  It's also likely that narrowing it down will be an iterative process.

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing the data in a database, a *transaction* is crucial.

Comment: He want to say that, if two user open the same page and trying to update record and if they hit the update button at the same time in web environment, How can he be able to deal in such situation.

Comment: No user can not sort data, user just update its information and this kind of problem occurs.

Comment: @bhargav; Edit your question and add code there instead putting in comment.

Comment: @bhargav: Not "sort", "store".  When storing data in a database, transactions provide a mechanism whereby an interaction with a database (or a set of interactions) becomes atomic.  That is, the entire interaction is encapsulated and whole, not partially affected by other means.

Comment: @David: yes its all done from database side. but i dont know why one person's data got inserted in other person's property details while updating. I think its related to data concurrency problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use locking mechanism?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.71).aspx

Worked fine for me in ASP.NET as far as I remember.

Comment: +1 [SyncLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y1470) in VB.Net